# Carrierwave/RMagick and PrawnPDF - opening image versions by url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, prawn

Been using PrawnPDF for one our projects and it's working marvellously! Kudos to the guys working on it. Got a quick question:

I am currently using Carrierwave with RMagick which manipulates and image:

```
version :pdf do
  process :resize_to_fit => [520, 0]
end
```

How do I go about using that version? I have the following code in my class at the moment:

```
image open("#{@artwork.artwork_asset}"), :width => 520
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it would be something like:

`image open("#{@artwork.artwork_asset.url(:pdf)}"), :width => 520`

You should also be able to drop the quotes:

`image open(@artwork.artwork_asset.url(:pdf)), :width => 520`

which I think is more legible.

This `.url(:version_name)` code is a function of carrierwave (documented [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/CarrierWave%2FUploader%2FVersions%3Aurl)) and you should be able to use it anywhere in your app, outside of prawn as well.